# javascriptでのルーティング

Tags: javascript

30個程度のjsファイルをconcatをして、jsファイルの1本化をした場合に、クライアントサイドでのルーティング処理はどのように実装するものでしょうか？

現在はpage.jsを使い、URLを判別して実行するという実装をしているのですが、
他の実装方法が無いか検討しています。
が、なかなか思い当たる物がありません。

ちなみに、SPAを開発しているわけではありません。
どなたかご助言頂きたく。
説明が足りなければ、お答えします。

Comment: ページごとに書いたjsを1ファイルにまとめたいが、各ページで全てのjsが実行されるのは困る、といった感じでしょうか。また `page.js` を使った方法の何が不満なのか、どうなってほしいのかが書いてあると、より具体的な回答が得られるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

とにかく、なにかの基準に沿ったルーターが不可欠です。それでルーターを通じてスクリプト（が含む関数）の実行が制御できますので、アプリケーションコードの構成に影響はほとんどないと思います。

SPAを開発していなくとも、ルーティングはある程度価値のあるアプローチかと。[director](https://github.com/flatiron/director#server-side-cli-routing)などでルートを構築したり...

```
  var routes = {
    '/script1': require('script1').hoge,
    '/script2': require('script2').hoge,
    '/books/view/:bookId': viewBook
  };

  var router = Router(routes);

  //
  // a global configuration setting.
  //
  router.configure({
    on: allroutes
  });
  router.init();
```

...或いは、本当にSPAに似てもいないサイトを開発していれば、クライアントサイドでのルーティングを完全に破棄して、いつものexpressルーティングも使用できます:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/script1/', function (req, res) {
  var script1 = require('script1');
  // ここでscript1を用いる関数などを使用
  res.send(script1.hoge);
});

router.on(/script2/, function () {
  // ここでscript2を用いる関数などを使用
  res.send(script2.hoge);
});


app.listen(3000)
```

アプリケーションコードの一本化については、`[browserify](http://browserify.org/)`などで実装後に簡単にできます。圧縮などは`[uglify](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/)`のような追加ツールを参照。

Comment: (アップはapp.js等のことを指していたのだと思いますが、カタカナにするならアプリ…だとスマホアプリに聞こえてしまうので、アプリケーションコードと言い換えてみました)

Comment: @unarist おっと、失礼しました。